Move email addresses from a word document into a CSV for importing into contacts
I have a word document that has a long list of email addresses that were pasted in from Outlook. They are typically in the format "Persons name" ; with semicolons separating the different addresses.
Right now this is a mess of information, eg "Smith, Bob" bob@smith.com; "Doe, Jane" jane@doe.com; and so on.
Is there an easy way to turn this list into something that could be imported into Outlook or Google contacts? Basically I need to turn this into a CSV where each of the names are in one column and each of the emails in another without the "" and <>
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.
What I tried:
When I turned this document into a semicolon separated document, each of the individual names and emails wind up in an individual cell, all in one row. But the name and email are in the same cell and they include the "" and <>

Here's what you do:

Convert the document to plain text.

Import into Excel; semicolon delimited.

Copy the row of data, click a new cell, transpose to get the data in one column:

In cell B1, paste this:
 =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(",", MID(A1, FIND("""", A1)+1, FIND("""", A1, FIND("""", A1)+1)-FIND("""", A1)-1))),
     MID(A1, FIND(",", A1)+2, FIND("""", A1, FIND(",", A1))-FIND(",", A1)-2),
     IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ", MID(A1, FIND("""", A1)+1, FIND("""", A1, FIND("""", A1)+1)-FIND("""", A1)-1))),
         LEFT(MID(A1, FIND("""", A1)+1, FIND("""", A1, FIND("""", A1)+1)-FIND("""", A1)-1), FIND(" ", MID(A1, FIND("""", A1)+1, FIND("""", A1, FIND("""", A1)+1)-FIND("""", A1)-1))-1),
         MID(A1, FIND("""", A1)+1, FIND("""", A1, FIND("""", A1)+1)-FIND("""", A1)-1)
     )
 )



That will grab the name whether it's formatted first, last or first last and if neither, just paste the value inside the ""

In cell C1 paste this:
 =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(",", MID(A1, FIND("""", A1)+1, FIND("""", A1, FIND("""", A1)+1)-FIND("""", A1)-1))),
     LEFT(MID(A1, FIND("""", A1)+1, FIND(",", A1)-FIND("""", A1)-1), FIND(",", A1)-FIND("""", A1)-1),
     IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ", MID(A1, FIND("""", A1)+1, FIND("""", A1, FIND("""", A1)+1)-FIND("""", A1)-1))),
         MID(A1, FIND(" ", A1)+1, FIND("""", A1, FIND(" ", A1))-FIND(" ", A1)-1),
         MID(A1, FIND("""", A1)+1, FIND("""", A1, FIND("""", A1)+1)-FIND("""", A1)-1)
     )
 )



will do the same for last name
6) Paste this in C1: =MID(A1, FIND("<", A1)+1, FIND(">", A1) - FIND("<", A1) - 1)
This pulls the email address out.
